# How can I put two ngFor in one div

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form which contain a list of checkboxes.

**I want to display a form input in front of each checkbox when this checkbox is checked**

This is my html :

```html
<div class = "checkbox">
    <label formArrayName="coverages" *ngFor="let coverage of coverageFormArray.controls;let i = index; let val of coverageFormArray.value;">
        <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [formControlName]="i"/>
        {{coveragestypes[i]}}
        <div *ngIf="val">
            <input type = "text">
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

But here the form input is always displayed even the checkbox is checked or not! I think the problem is related to the directive ngFor where I put two loops `let coverage of coverageFormArray.controls` and `let val of coverageFormArray.value` ? Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple `*ngFor`s in the same element as those are structural directives and angular handles them in a specific way (basically for each structural directive it creates an `ng-template` element which then holds the directive itself, you can read more about it here:
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives, understanding that really makes it very clear why we can't have multiple structutral directives on the same element).

So you cannot use two `ngFor`s on the same element, but you can use the index, if both arrays are of the same size, to check whether or not there is a value.

You did not give an example of the data format, so I'm probably going to give an example that will have to be adapted.

```html
<div class = "checkbox">
    <label formArrayName="coverages" *ngFor="let coverage of coverageFormArray.controls;let i = index;">
        <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [formControlName]="i"/>
        {{ coveragestypes[i] }}
        <div *ngIf="coverage.value">
            <input type = "text">
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

In addition, I recommend using `ng-container` instead of html tag that are only use to apply an Angular directive.

So my final solution would be.

```html
<div class = "checkbox">
    <label formArrayName="coverages" *ngFor="let coverage of coverageFormArray.controls;let i = index;">
        <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [formControlName]="i"/>
        {{ coveragestypes[i] }}
        <ng-container *ngIf="coverage.value">
            <input type = "text">
        </ng-container>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer :), I would like to add that the inability to use two `*ngFor`s is related to them being structural directives which actually create `ng-template` elements under the hood (as you can see here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives ).
Understanding that makes it very clear why no more than one structural directive can be applied to the same element :)

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz It should be in the answer. Could you add it ?

Comment: Sure, that'll be my pleasure :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for appreciating the input :)